# Is it possible to connect Power BI to a kdb database via ODBC driver?

Tags: odbc, powerbi, kdb

I am unable to connect to a kdb+ database in Power BI via the qodbc3 ODBC driver. After selecting Get Data -> Other -> ODBC and selecting a qodbc driver connection that I know works (used without issue by Tableau) I get stuck at the navigator window and there is no option to load a table.

[image: Image of Power BI Navigator window with no option to load table]

My concern is that kdb driver is not compatible with Power BI which is causing Power BI to not be able to find database tables.

Comment: Whlist it might be possible, it'll probably be completely useless - KDB only have very limited support for SQL and i suspect that, since you're using Power BI, you'll require all sorts of SQL funkiness.

Answer (score 2):

Although this option was not available back when the question was asked, today's solution to this problem would be to use the Simba ODBC Driver:

https://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/odbc-simba/

> The primary target for this release is support for:
>
> - Tableau (certification compliance included)
> - **PowerBI**
> - Excel

Comment: Have you or anyone else actually gotten it to accept kdb-native queries? I have powerBI<>kdb working but it only accepts sql-native queries from what I can see

Comment: It's been a long time since I used that and I don't remember exactly, but I think some drivers were exposing functions to execute q code. Something like `q('your q code here')`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I got it to work eventually! Some drivers (such as ODBC3) do expose a `q(' ... ')` wrapper like you said, but the Simba driver doesn't. Simba driver exposes it using queries like `{ native 'select from t where col=123' COLUMNS()}` and `{ native 'myFunc' PASSING('123':long) COLUMNS() }`